# can not install apk from email attachment to phone getting parsing error

Tags: android

I have built a test android app and signed it successfully and then sent it to someone to test via email.  They click on the attachment in the email on their android phone and get a parsing error.

They have 2.1 android

the test app was built using 2.2

would that cause an issue?

can email attachments of apk files not be installed directly to the phone?

Comment: built using 2.2 could be the problem if the minimum sdk is 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only would install from webserver link... not from email attachment on one persons phone.  So I guess use weblink or market when possible is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem - sending the app via email to myself worked fine, but out to a friend failed (they were using Yahoo mail).

I've since put it on a webserver and sent the URL instead  - no reports yet on whether that worked, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: the initial person I sent it to uses gmail.  no luck.  The second person I sent it to for testing used a different email server and it worked.  He had to change the setting to allow installing none market apps, but that was all.  The first person did not get the none market notice, simply parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android 2.2 this was not possible in the Gmail app. There are several helper apps that facilitate this functionality on 2.1 and lower, one of which is APKatcher (developed by yours truly). The easiest way is just to send URLs to a hosted copy which you've found.